# Anaconda Virtual Environment Tensorflow allocates 95% of memory and the process is very slow

Tags: linux, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, nvidia

I have a server running on CentOS 7 where I am trying to create a conda environment to run some GPU (NVIDIA) processes.
This is what I did:

1. created a conda env with python 3.6
2. conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.14 keras=2.2.4

When I tried to train a model, I can see that GPU is getting worked by monitoring GPU memory usage.
However, the issue is that tensorflow allocates about 95% of memory for the model when I configure it and the process is very slow such that I would never get to the point where I actually train images.

So, I tried to limit the memory allocation, but the slow process persists.

I also tried TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=True, but the process is still slow while GPU gets worked and fan kicks in after a minute or so.

Lastly, here are the different versions that I have tried:

1. tensorflow-gpu=1.14, keras=2.2.4, cudatoolkit=10.0, cudnn=7.6.5
2. tensorflow-gpu=1.14, keras=2.2.4, cudatoolkit=10.1, cudnn=7.6.5
3. tensorflow-gpu=1.12, keras=2.2.4, cudatoolkit=9.2, cudnn=7.6.5

Any help would be much much appreciated!!
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try limiting GPU memory growth as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)?